# Can we add Style Library Resources(CSS, JS, Images) on Anonymous SharePoint Application Page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, application-pages, style-library

I have created a SharePoint Application Page in SharePoint 2016. This page is anonymous.

I have used some style library resources on this page but when i open this page it is redirecting me to login page. I  am assuming  that this behavior is because it cannot  access style library resources  i am using on application page.

Remember Site does not has anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable anonymous access in style library to compare the result.